# Evan Chen Geometry

Tags: geometry

[image]

Today I started Evan Chen's geometry book. I figured question (a) myself but please show me your solution to verify mine. I couldn't question (b) and if you helped me I would be grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

XY is parallel with BC(can you find why?).BC is perpendicular on AX therefore XY is also perpendicular on AX ,that means AY is a diameter of (ABC).

Comment: Because of similarity?

Comment: Your solution is so easy! In hints was said that HBYC is a parallelogram. I figured it why it is parallelogram but how can I solve this problem with the hint?

Comment: In triangle XYH, BC bisects legs HX and HY, this means it is parallel with base XY.

Comment: @sirous Yes I got it. What do you think about given hint in the book? How the fact that HBYC is parallelogram helps us in this problem?

Comment: @NikaChelidze Have you proved that $X$ and $Y$ lie on the circle $(ABC)$?

Comment: @user Yes I have but as I mentioned I wanted other solutions to verify mine. I have connected (ABC) center "O" with C and B and proved with angle chasing that OC and OB are equal to OX and OY

Comment: @NikaChelidze If you do not need a proof that $X$ and $Y$ lie on the circle, the above proof that $AY$ is the circle diameter is perfect. If you need such a proof you should not accept answer which does not provide it. And you should not insist on applying a hint which you never mentioned in the question.

Comment: I have mentioned hint in my second comment. Also these two problems are distinct and I  think all the proofs are acceptable for each one.

Comment: @NikaChelidze You should formulate the complete problem in the question, not in a comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108331/discussion-between-nika-chelidze-and-user).

Answer (score 2):

Observe:
$$\angle BHC=\pi-\angle BCH-\angle CBH=\pi-\left(\frac\pi2-\angle ABC\right)-\left(\frac\pi2-\angle BCA\right)=\pi-\angle BAC.
$$

Now by the construction the points $X$ and $Y$ lie in the other half-plane created by line $(BC)$ than the point $A$. Moreover as easy to verify:
$$
\triangle BXC\cong \triangle BHC; \;  \triangle BYC\cong \triangle BHC
\implies \angle BXC=\angle BYC=\angle BHC =\pi-\angle BAC,
$$
whence the points $X$ and $Y$ lie on the circle $ABC$.

Further with $X'=(HX)\cap(BC)$, $Y'=(HY)\cap(BC)$ we have
$$
\triangle HXY\sim\triangle HX'Y'\implies XY\parallel BC\implies XY\perp AX,
$$
so that $AY$ is the diameter of $(ABC)$ by Thales's theorem.

Comment: Thanks! Now I got why hint was to use a parallelogram.